# Javascript call object in another one

Tags: javascript

I should do a JS game for school, but I need help on this :

```
var player1 = {
  char: kitana,
  x: 150,
  y: 50,
  life: 100,
  facing: 1,
  currentAnimation: "move",
  currentFrame: 0,
  frameSlow :0,
  currentImage: new Image(),
};

 var player2 = {
      char: kitana,
      x: 150,
      y: 50,
      life: 100,
      facing: 1,
      currentAnimation: "move",
      currentFrame: 0,
      frameSlow :0,
      currentImage: new Image(),
    };

var kitana = {
  hitbox :{
    left : 5,
    right : 100,
  },
  images : {
    move:[],
    punch: [],
  },
};
```

I would like to put the "kitana" object by reference in "player", how can i do that easily ?

The goal is that I could use something like `player1.char.images.move[0] = "exemple";` and then use it with `player2.char.images.move[0]`

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `kitana` object definition *before* players and you will have correct references:

```
var kitana = {
    hitbox: {
        left: 5,
        right: 100,
    },
    images: {
        move: [],
        punch: [],
    },
};

var player1 = {
    char: kitana,
    x: 150,
    y: 50,
    life: 100,
    facing: 1,
    currentAnimation: "move",
    currentFrame: 0,
    frameSlow: 0,
    currentImage: new Image(),
};

var player2 = {
    char: kitana,
    x: 150,
    y: 50,
    life: 100,
    facing: 1,
    currentAnimation: "move",
    currentFrame: 0,
    frameSlow: 0,
    currentImage: new Image(),
};
```